# How to combine startswith and IF for pandas

Tags: pandas, if-statement, startswith

I am trying to do 2 things - 1st use a startswith in a df to identify which rows contain the condition, and 2nd add a specific TAG to a column. I have been able to do both things correctly but separately - but unsuccessful in combining.

This is an example of the content in the interest column df 'PartNumber' (GLO, GLOA, GLO1, GLOA2, GLO9, etc) the common denominator is the "GLO" and I want the tag to be added "GLO Series".

This code successfully can ID the rows that have the starting condition

```
search = 'GLO'
search_series = df['PartNumber'].str.startswith(search, na= False)
df[search_series]
```

This code successfully can ID the row that has the specific condition - I know it is because of the '=='. The challenge is that I have to call out the specific part, which is what I do not know all values, hence my attempt to do the 'startswith'

```
df.loc[(df['PartNumber']== 'GLOA2'),'TAG_2']='Glo Series'
print (df)
```

I tried to combine both which did not work.

I am trying to achieve once completed a kind of "If this / then that" for several conditions summarized as follows:

df [PartNumber] used to ID set conditions-based on starting characters ('GLO', 'FL0', 'MOW')
depending on this then a value would be placed in a set column resulting in ('Glo series', 'Flo series', 'Mow series')

Comment: kindly share sample dataset with expected output. data, not pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that *TAG_2* column contains initially some other values
(I marked them with *?*):

```
      ind PartNumber  Val TAG_2
0  110101        ABC   20     ?
1  110102        GLO   22     ?
2  110103       GLO1   24     ?
3  110104       GLO2   26     ?
4  110105        XYZ   28     ?
```

To do your task in one go (assuming that you set *search* to the
wanted value) you can run:

```
df.TAG_2.mask(df['PartNumber'].str.startswith(search, na=False), 'Glo Series', inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
      ind PartNumber  Val       TAG_2
0  110101        ABC   20           ?
1  110102        GLO   22  Glo Series
2  110103       GLO1   24  Glo Series
3  110104       GLO2   26  Glo Series
4  110105        XYZ   28           ?
```

## Part 2

To detect **multiple** group prefixes and set *TAG_2* to corresponding
group names, take a different approach.

1. Define a Series with index composed of "wanted" prefixes and corresponding
   group names as values:

   ```
   search = pd.Series(['Glo Series', 'Flo Series', 'Mow  Series'],
       index=['GLO', 'FLO', 'MOW'])
   ```
2. Define a function to get the part series name from a part number:

   ```
   def getSer(PartNo):
       for idx, val in search.iteritems():
           if PartNo.startswith(idx):
               return val
       return 'Alphabet start' if PartNo < search.index.min() else 'Alphabet end'
   ```

   Note that if no match has been found in the loop, the last instruction
   returns either *'Alphabet start'* or *'Alphabet end'* (as you asked for
   in your comment).
3. Generate the result updating *TAG_2* (in place) with the result
   of application of the above function:

   ```
   df.TAG_2.update(df.PartNumber.apply(getSer))
   ```

This time, to test this code, I used a DataFrame containing:

```
      ind PartNumber  Val TAG_2
0  110101      ABC30   20     ?
1  110102      FLO34   22     ?
2  110103      GLO10   24     ?
3  110104      GLO22   26     ?
4  110105      XYZ26   28     ?
5  110105      MOW55   30     ?
6  110105      XYZ99   28     ?
```

After the above *updata* the result is:

```
      ind PartNumber  Val           TAG_2
0  110101      ABC30   20  Alphabet start
1  110102      FLO34   22      Flo Series
2  110103      GLO10   24      Glo Series
3  110104      GLO22   26      Glo Series
4  110105      XYZ26   28    Alphabet end
5  110105      MOW55   30     Mow  Series
6  110105      XYZ99   28    Alphabet end
```

If you have more "wanted" groups, change *search* variable accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Valdi - this worked!! How can we adapt so that this can do it for multiple searches? in your example let's say that ABC would have a TAG_2 of "alphabet start" and XYZ a TAG_2 of "alphabet end".

Comment: Thanks Valdi! worked great.. how can we adjust to now add a level of sophistication. if we were to add a column to the df, and based on that the TAG_2 value would change. Something like if we had GroupA & GroupB in another column in the df; so PartNumber 'FLO34' linked to GroupA would have TAG_2 'Flo Series A', however if  it would be 'FLO34' linked to GroupB it would say on TAG_2 'Flo Series B'.